# RStudio snippet not working

Tags: r, markdown, code-snippets

I'm utilizing a Macbook pro running "El Capitan" and RStudio is version 0.99.902. I'm writing a Rmd document. I want to utilize the snippets that RStudio has built in and create my own also. By clicking Preference => Code; I can see that "Enable code snippets" is checked. However, while trying to utilize any snippet the completion is not performed. If I typed just `r` I should get this block of code, but nothing hapen

````
snippet r
    ```{r ${1:label}, ${2:options}}
    ${0}
    ```
````

I also create a simple snippet:

```
snippet dthen
    %>%
```

None of the markdown snippet seems to work. Do I'm doing something wrong or any setting has to be done?

Comment: Same problem here using RStudio Server Pro or RStudio Desktop for Mac (El Cap).  R snippets inside code blocks work, but snippets outside code blocks (Markdown snippets) do not work.

Answer (score 6):

You can invoke code snippets in Markdown in RStudio using Shift+Tab after typing the snippet, but it will not currently prompt you to expand the snippet, either with Tab or by just waiting.  I thought this was a bug, but the discussion [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/535) says it's intended, just still-to-be-documented.

Comment: Not really a solution, but perhaps you can make it work. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41664105/5784831)

Answer (score 1):

In `Tools > Global Options > Code > Editing > Edit Snippets`, go to the section "Markdown" and paste your snippet there. Save, OK, apply. Type `r` in your Rmd document (not within in a R code chunk) and click Shift+Tab. If it still does not work, try to create a new "R markdown" file (File > New file > R markdown) and check if it works there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same trouble recently. Snippets must be indented when customized, instead if an space is inserted it won't work