# Any easy way to insert custom text snippets in RMarkdown files in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

When writing an RMarkdown file in RStudio, I'd like to be able to insert common text snippets using a keyboard shortcut.  On the one hand, there are code snippets in RStudio, but [they don't seem to work for Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748516/rstudio-snippet-not-working#comment65682879_37748516).  So I'd settle for any other way to create a custom keyboard shortcut for inserting a pre-specified piece of custom text, while I wait for that bug to be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out you *can* use code snippets in Markdown in RStudio.  Although they don't *seem* to work at first, you can force snippet expansion using Shift+Tab, as described [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/535).  The RStudio team says they'll add that to the official documentation in the future.

Comment: This doesn't work outside of chunks for me

Comment: I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161446/rstudio-keyboard-shortcut-inline-code)