# Is there a keyboard shortcut to insert R code inline in RMarkdown?

Tags: insert, keyboard, markdown, shortcut

I have been trying to find a shortcut to insert

```
`r `
```

and this is because I frequently write my code in different computer with different keyboards and it is quite complicated to find the ` symbol on each one.

Is there a way I can program a shortcut for such symbol? Markdown help has no answer to this

I have tried to insert a code chunk with `Ctrl + Alt + I` but it also takes some time to edit from

````
```{r}
````

to the desired

```
`r `
```

Comment: The keyboard commands will depend on the editor/IDE you are using. You should update your question with that information, and tag it so that people who monitor, for example, the [rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rstudio) tag will see your question.

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161446/rstudio-keyboard-shortcut-inline-code

Comment: Totally right @NickK9, that's what I was looking for