# the `preamble.tex` is not processed for the `gitbook` output

Tags: bookdown

As it was said in a comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655383/r-markdown-similar-feature-to-newcommand-in-latex) -- `bookdown`s `gitbook` does not propagate things like `\newcommand` that work fine for the `pdf_book` output.

Is there a better workaround than moving the `\newcommand` to the first chapter's `01-intro.Rmd` markdown file? This works but it somehow messes up the clean markdown syntax.

Or is there even a fix for this issue? (I didn't find anything related in the `bookdown` [issue tracker](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues))

Comment: I did some more tests (see my comment in the URL you link to). I would recommend to file a (bug/usage) report and point out that post in the issue tracker.